# draw square in image with react native

Tags: android, react-native, opencv, expo, drawing

Currently I am building an android app using react native expo, and I need to draw squares on the image based on coordinates. Is there any library that supports drawing squares on images like opencv in react native?

Comment: You can use [react-native-canvas](https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas) library. There is also [opencv 3](https://github.com/adamgf/react-native-opencv3) implementation but its not actively maintained.

Comment: I tried canvas but its drawing coordinates are not based on the image but on the Image View

Comment: I want to use like this `let src = cv.imread('canvasInput',0); \n
let s = new cv.Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255); \n
cv.rectangle(src, new cv.Point(8, 8), new cv.Point(300, 300), s, 2);`